# How to rescale a dataframe to a different index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df like this:

```
>>> df
   start  stop                phrase  speaker
0   1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes        1
1   5.13  5.45                  okay        0
2   5.51  5.99  i can help with that        0
3   7.23  8.12               awesome        1
4   8.87  9.65            lets begin        0
```

As you can see, it has 4 columns, the start and stop time of the phrase, the phrase, and the label of who said the phrase.

I want to get this transcript onto a uniform time index. However, because some phrases occur within the same second, I need the index to be less than one second, such as a quarter of a second. Ultimately, I'd like to experiment with different indices, from a quarter to a tenth of a second.

First, if helpful, here is code to reproduce the df.

```
>>> data = \
[
    (1.22, 3.13, 'im looking for shoes', 1),
    (5.13, 5.45, 'okay', 0),
    (5.51, 5.99, 'i can help with that', 0),
    (7.23, 8.12, 'awesome', 1),
    (8.87, 9.65, 'lets begin', 0)
]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.columns=['start','stop','phrase','speaker']
```

I have a decent solution to get this onto the seconds level. It goes like this:

```
def convert(df):
    df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['stop'].sub(df['start']).add(1))]
    df['frames'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(df['start'])
    df = df.reset_index()
    df['frames'] = df.frames.astype(int)
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['frames'])
    df = pd.concat([pd.Series(range(0, df.loc[0, 'frames']), name='frames').to_frame(), df]).reset_index(drop=True) 
    s = df['frames'].astype(int)
    df = df.set_index('frames').reindex(range(s.min(), s.max() + 1)).reset_index()
    return df
```

Which returns:

```
>>> convert(df)
   frames  index  start  stop                phrase  speaker
0       0    NaN    NaN   NaN                   NaN      NaN
1       1    0.0   1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
2       2    0.0   1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
3       3    NaN    NaN   NaN                   NaN      NaN
4       4    NaN    NaN   NaN                   NaN      NaN
5       5    1.0   5.13  5.45                  okay      0.0
6       6    NaN    NaN   NaN                   NaN      NaN
7       7    3.0   7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0
8       8    4.0   8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0
```

This is insufficent because I am missing the data for the phrase `i can help with that`. I am missing this phrase because it is the second phrase to start and stop within the second `5`. This is why I need to expand to every quarter or tenth of a second. However, I don't know how to do this, as I keep running into the error of not being able to set an index by floats (quarter or tenth of seconds).

I want it to look like this for quarter second index:

```
   frames  index  start  stop                phrase  speaker
0       0    
1      .25
2      .50
3      .75
4     1.00    
5     1.25      1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
6     1.50      1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
7     1.75      1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
8     2.00      1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
10    2.25      1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
11    2.50      1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
12    2.75      1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
13    3.00      1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0
14    3.25
15    3.50
16    3.75
17    4.00    
18    4.25
19    4.50
20    4.75
21    5.00      5.13  5.45                  okay      0.0
22    5.25      5.13  5.45                  okay      0.0
23    5.50      5.51  5.99  i can help with that      0.0
24    5.75      5.51  5.99  i can help with that      0.0
25    6.00
26    6.25
27    6.50
28    6.75
29    7.00      7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0
30    7.25      7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0
31    7.50      7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0
32    7.75      7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0
33    8.00      7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0
34    8.25 
35    8.50 
36    8.75      8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0
37    9.00      8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0
38    9.25      8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0
30    9.50      8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0
40    9.75
```

Comment: If you remove the `\ ` from `data =` you can't build correctly your dataframe. It raises a SyntaxError (for me)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a typo, but I guess it was essential. Its back in.

Comment: You have some conflicting joining results here.  Let's look at 'Im looking for shoes' starts value of 1.22, you have it starting on index 1.25, first .25 interval after.  Now look at 'okay' start value of 5.13, you have it startin on index 5.00.  This is matching .35 interval before.  This conflicts with the first join.  Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = \
[
    (1.22, 3.13, 'im looking for shoes', 1),
    (5.13, 5.45, 'okay', 0),
    (5.51, 5.99, 'i can help with that', 0),
    (7.23, 8.12, 'awesome', 1),
    (8.87, 9.65, 'lets begin', 0)
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns=['start','stop','phrase','speaker']


step=.25
df['range'] = [np.arange(s,e+step,step) for s,e  in zip(df['start'],df['stop'])]
dfe = df.explode('range')
dfe['range'] = dfe['range'].astype(float)
dfe = dfe.sort_values('range')

dfi = pd.DataFrame({'frame':np.arange(0, df['stop'].max()+step, step)})

df_out = pd.concat([pd.merge_asof(dfi, dfe, left_on='frame', right_on='range', direction='forward', tolerance=step),
pd.merge_asof(dfi, dfe, left_on='frame', right_on='range', direction='backward', tolerance=step)]).groupby('frame').first()

df_out
```

Output:

```
       start  stop                phrase  speaker  range
frame                                                   
0.00     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
0.25     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
0.50     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
0.75     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
1.00    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   1.22
1.25    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   1.47
1.50    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   1.72
1.75    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   1.97
2.00    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   2.22
2.25    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   2.47
2.50    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   2.72
2.75    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   2.97
3.00    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   3.22
3.25    1.22  3.13  im looking for shoes      1.0   3.22
3.50     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
3.75     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
4.00     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
4.25     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
4.50     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
4.75     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
5.00    5.13  5.45                  okay      0.0   5.13
5.25    5.13  5.45                  okay      0.0   5.38
5.50    5.51  5.99  i can help with that      0.0   5.51
5.75    5.51  5.99  i can help with that      0.0   5.76
6.00    5.51  5.99  i can help with that      0.0   6.01
6.25    5.51  5.99  i can help with that      0.0   6.01
6.50     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
6.75     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
7.00    7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0   7.23
7.25    7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0   7.48
7.50    7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0   7.73
7.75    7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0   7.98
8.00    7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0   8.23
8.25    7.23  8.12               awesome      1.0   8.23
8.50     NaN   NaN                  None      NaN    NaN
8.75    8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0   8.87
9.00    8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0   9.12
9.25    8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0   9.37
9.50    8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0   9.62
9.75    8.87  9.65            lets begin      0.0   9.87
```